# Get request: rewrite URL with .htacces

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url

Im trying to make my url look like this:

http://example.com/photo-album-detail/jan-2016

Currently it looks like: http://example.com/photo-album-detail/?album=jan-2016

How could ik achieve this?

What i have now is:

```
RewriteRule ^photo-album-detail/* photo-album-detail/?album=$1
```

But this does not seem to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite rule is incomplete - you need to capture the album value:

```
RewriteRule ^photo-album-detail/(.+)$   photo-album-detail/?album=$1 [L]
```

Add this on the top of your htaccess, with `RewriteEngine on` before.

Comment: this does not seem to do anything :/

Comment: Could you try with the updated rule and see if it help?

Comment: This is the url im linking to: http://example.com/photo-album-detail/?album=jan-2016 it should change to http://example.com/photo-album-detail/jan-2016 right? still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not understanding how mod_rewrite works.

The URL you are matching against in this rule

```
RewriteRule ^photo-album-detail/(.+) photo-album-detail/?album=$1 [L]
```

Is this type of URL `http://example.com/photo-album-detail/jan-2016` because that is the pattern your are matching against.

If you would like to redirect based on using this type of URL `http://example.com/photo-album-detail/?album=jan-2016` then you need to match on the `query string` or `the request`.

These are the combined rules you need.

```
RewriteEngine On
#if request is a real file or directory do nothing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

#redirect the old query string URL to the rewritten URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /photo-album-detail/\?album=([^&\s]+)
RewriteRule ^ /photo-album-detail/%1? [R=302,L]

#internally rewrite pretty URL to querystring
RewriteRule ^photo-album-detail/(.+) /photo-album-detail/?album=$1 [L]
```

Let me know how that works for you.

Comment: Thanks for helping me, but it does not seem to work :/
it not doing anything it looks like

Comment: Is your .htaccess file enabled? You need to make sure `AllowOverride All` is set in your config.